# SFDX behavior change

Tags: salesforcedx

I have been using SFDX since it was released and all of a sudden it is behaving differently. When I push my source to a scratch org and then run a status without making any changes I see a ton of Remote Changes.

If I actually pull I can see the changes that I did not make. Theses changes consist of remove namespaces from code, removing extra lines at the bottom of a file, adding fields to permission sets that dont have read or edit permission, etc.

I am very confused why these remote changes are being pulled down if I did not make them.

Also once I pulled down, created a new scratch org, and pushed, there are now errors because of the pull.

One really strange issue is it pulled down a field meta.xml file and put it in the object folder. This of course caused errors when pushing. How does SFDX pull down something in error like that.

I have updated sfdx recently as I thought it could be that.

Not really sure what is going on.

Comment: please raise this on the https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli. Also, note you can always revert to the previous version of the cli by doing sfdx plugins:install salesforcedx@41.4.1 what ever version works.